# How to assign a clicked category name to a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, navigation

I am attempting to build a category navigation system and so far have all my tables set up and indexed in mysql. My issue is understanding the logic for retrieving the categories I want using php.

I am thinking I need something like:

On click - store clicked category name in variable `$category` - query variable against database

```
SELECT subcategory_name FROM subcategories WHERE parent = "$category"
```

Does this sound right? I think there is not an on click function in php so I am unsure which function should I look into that I can use to assign the category name I click to the variable?

Comment: PHP is a server side language. To do anything "on click" you'll have to use javascript. If you're attempting to build, say a multi level menu system, your best bet is to send all categories and subcategories to the page and render it as an unordered list. From that you can then use any of the 293238 already made menu scripts out there.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're going? a 'click' would be a click on a link? Then you could send the category as a GET variable (url.php?cat=category_name)

Comment: @PtPazuzu yeah I basically want to click on a link and have a query return from the database all the links associated with the one I have clicked.

Comment: @Bing I don't suppose you know any of those scripts that would support many to many relationships between categories and subcategories? I've searched and searched for an existing script with no joy whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you want to use javascript in your app. You may want to use an anchor tag with $_GET variables to past the selected category e.g

```
// You can style the anchor tag to look like a button
<a href='querypage.php?category=books'>Select Books category</a>
```

On the page querypage.php, you can get the clicked category like this:

```
$category = $_GET['category'];
// Then you can run your query
SELECT subcategory_name FROM subcategories WHERE parent = "$category"
```

Comment: And you'll want to escape '$category' before running that query

Comment: @Chibuzo That looks more like what I'm after! Thankyou! I will look into it and give it a whirl.

Comment: I'm glad you like it. Remember to sanitize the category variable like this...  $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category']);

Answer (score 0):

You are right there is no on click event in PHP. You will need to send an ajax (or normal) request (GET) if you want to run any thing on server (that is what .NET do in the background :))